# Calculate the maximum of $\sum_{1\le i<j<k\le 100}a_ia_ja_k$ where $\sum a_i = 2007$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation

> Calculate the maximum of $$\sum_{1\le i<j<k\le 100}a_ia_ja_k$$ where $\sum a_i = 2007$.

This is a question that I've seen long before and not been able to solve it.

My initial thought is that the more even $a_i$ is, the larger the sum will be. Hence, when there are $93$ $20$s and $7$ $21$s, the sum will supposedly become the biggest.

But I got stuck on proving this point. I'd appreciate some help.

PS. Can we extend the problem, e.g. $100$ to $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ and $2007$ to $k>n\land k\in\mathbb{N}_+$?

Comment: I think you meant $\sum a_i =2007$, and $a_i$'s are all non-negative integers.

Comment: Hint: fix $a_3, \ldots, a_{100}$, and prove that $|a_1-a_2|\le 1$ for the maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is completely correct.

Suppose the maximum is achieved for a set of $a_i$ where two of them, $a$ and $b$ say, are such that $b\ge a+2$ and consider the effect of changing $a$ to $a+1$ and $b$ to $b-1$.

Split up the terms in the original summation into those involving neither $a$ nor $b$, involving $a$ not $b$, involving $b$ not $a$, involving both. Let these add up to $N,Xa,Xb,Yab$, respectively.

Then the sum $N+Xa+Xb+Yab$ is changed to $N+X(a+1)+X(b-1)+Y(a+1)(b-1)$ i.e. a positive change of $Y(b-a-1)$.

We can conclude that the $a_i$ take at most two values. Furthermore, we can see that this proof generalises very easily.

Over to you now?

Comment: My calculations give a change of $Y(b-a-1)$.

Comment: And mine! Thanks - just a typo.

Comment: Why don't you correct it?

Comment: Mm! I thought I had done.

Comment: The prefactor $Y$ is still missing.

Comment: Thanks, my excuse for such sloppiness is  that having drafted a solution for this I've been rather distracted by some very sad family news. Thanks again for reading the proof carefully and pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: My condolences. I have edited.

Comment: This really helps a lot to me! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The value could reach infinity as we can take $a_{1}=-n ,a_{2}=-n , a_{3}=2007,a_{4}=2n$ and $a_{j}=0$ for all $j\geq 5$ then $$S=a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}+a_{1}a_{2}a_{4}+a_{1}a_{3}a_{4}+a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}=2007n^{2}+2n^{3}-8028n^{2}$$ Choosing $n\rightarrow \infty$
We have $$S\rightarrow \infty$$